# Cannot Publish new Google Sheets Editor Addon because of invalid App Configuration error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a Email Merge App which used to be container-bound, but my goal is to move it to an internal addOn for Sheets so my team can use it. The App inserts values from a Sheet into a Gmail Draft and sends it to the list of recipients, nothing special. Yet the way to publishing has been special, sadly. I've developed projects before, but they are Workspace Addon, yet this project requires it to be a Sheets addon.

In order to publish the addOn I've followed the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish), but I get the following error in the `App Configuration` (GCP > Marketplace SDK) when I try and save the Script and Deployment Ids ([new deployments auto creates a version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#creating_a_version)):

`Project Key is not associated with the current project or the script version doesn't exist.`

Yet I can assure the following, my **Script**:

1. has been created
2. is **not** bound to a container
3. is connected to the GCP project (Settings > GCP Project === my GCP project)
4. an active deployment/version exists

I can also assure the following from the **Marketplace SDK**

1. I've only selected the Sheet's Addon
2. I've entered the correct Script Id (Settings > Script Id)
3. I've entered the correct deployment Id (Deploy > Manage > Active > Deployment Id)

Further Background Information of what I've tried and which did not lead to success:

1. When deploying my Script, I've initially selected Addon and then I tried API Executable
2. I've created multiple deployments and tried them
3. I've tried to set the access level on the deployment to anyone in my org
4. I've changed the GCP project in my Script and changed it back to the correct one
5. I've slept a night over it and tried the next morning
6. My next move would be to restart *my computer* out of hopelessness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key was to to use the Version Number, not the actual Version / Deployment Id. Basically, within the Marketplace SDK > Configuration, the following fields were applied:

- Script Id = A 57-ish alphanumeric string taken from:  Apps Script Project > Project Settings > Script ID
- Version Number = A number, e.g. 1, 12, 32 taken from: Apps Script Project >  Manage Deployments > the number which is shown in the active deployment, i.e the Version **4** on Sep 19, 2021

Comment: OMG thank you!! I've been stuck on this forever; Google should make it clearer that it should be the version number and not the deployment ID

The only other change I made to get it working was to enable "Share > General Access > Anyone with the link"